# Why Angular HttpClient response is null?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, httpclient, angular7

**My Environments:**

- Shop RestController : Spring Boot

  - on localhost laptopn ubuntu 18:04
- ShopService: Angular HttpClient

  - on localhost desktop pc windows 10

**Problem:**

My get request via HttpClient got the response null.
But if I use postman or on browser, I got my expected response body.

*Angular Code:*

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://pc01:8081/shopsystem/shops';
const  SHOP_NAME = 'Muster Shop';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShopService {

  shop$: Shop;
  address$: Address;
  owner$: Owner;

  //header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getShop(): Observable<Shop>{
    return this.http.get<Shop>(BASE_URL + '/' + SHOP_NAME);
  }
```

*Response-Header:*

[image]

*Response:*

[image]

*Request on postman:*

[image]

*Spring Boot controller:*

[image]

I have already tried with Observable with any and HttpHeaders with application/json
but same response.

Another thing: If my Spring Boot controller returns a List then I got the response body with contents.

**Question:**

Why I got a null or empty body in my HttpClient request?

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: show your Get method in the spring boot controller

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I edited my question with my spring boot controller

Comment: Have you tried to set it up without a space in the uri? Change `muster shop` to `musterShop` and see if you are still getting the null

Comment: I got 404 like expected from backend.                                                         
Request URL: http://pc01:8081/shopsystem/shops/MusterShop
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404

Comment: Cause your auto wired service is looking for `muster shop` when you check if its present which it's not cause you changed it in angular.  So either change it there or do what Maciej's answer says. both would work.  Either way, the `%20` space encoding is what the issue is

Comment: But If I call it from postman or on browser I go my response. Ok now I changed it on my db name to 'mustershop' and I got no response data like before on httpclient but on postman I got the reponse.

Comment: Does the request reach your controller in both cases? Do you have any errors in the Chrome console? I suspect it is a CORS issue as your server is running on a different machine.

Comment: No error in the chrome console cause I use cors add-on to enable cors. As I said if my spring boot controller returns List<Shop> I got the response with contents.

Comment: I recon it’s your addon stuffing things up. Turn it off and see what happens. Run the apps on same machine and see what happens. Enable Cors properly in spring boot and see what happens. Looks like you have some debugging to do.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)  yes I have to enable cors on spring boot controller

Answer (score 1):

Your Angular HttpClient encodes the space in the path variable so it comes to the RestController as **Muster%20Shop**.

Then you try to find a record with that exact name which does not exist.

You have to decode the `@PathVariable` before you send it to your query as **Muster Shop**.

Comment: But Spring Boot decode it automatically I can see it on my spring boot log. If my request from HttpClient reach my spring boot its calls the expected service and returns the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

add annotation @CrossOrigin to your Controller class

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {

    private final FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    private final GameService service;


    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public GameDTO getUserbyID(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.info("get {} at {}", service.getUserbyID(id), Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        return service.getUserbyID(id);
    }
```

Comment: A more detailed answer would have included a code sample with the recommended fix.

Answer (score 0):

It might be resolved but i've been dealing with somenthing similar i think and when it comes to observables in HttpClient you need to add a property in the options param of the http request method. i. e.

[image]

It's somenthing that never happened before to me, but since im not the one who made the API cant be sure if there's somenthing in backend that may be related to this issue.